# Spacing points automatically instead of by hand using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile

Is there a way to put points out at 10m apart instead of doing it all by hand?

My boss thinks it can be done in Excel but the only way I know how is to enter in each lat, long then import it that way.

Comment: The title of this Question is misleading, since you want to do the *opposite* of what the title states.

Answer (score 7):

[Generate Points Along Line](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/generate-points-along-lines.htm) geoprocessing tool:

> Creates point features along lines or polygons at fixed intervals or by percentage

[Construct Points](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/creating-new-features/creating-new-points-along-a-line.htm) tool on the editing toolbar:

> Creates new point features at intervals along a selected line.

Another option (thanks @mkennedy) is [Create Fishnet](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/create-fishnet.htm) geoprocessing tool with the label points option set to true:

> In addition to creating the output fishnet, a new point feature class is created with label points at the center of each fishnet cell if the Create Label Points parameter is checked.

Comment: Another option is Create Fishnet with the label points option set to true.

Comment: @mkennedy absolutely, I'd forgotten that one.